sourcing a file within a bash script is not working
I have the following files
$ cat sourceme
alias ll='ls -l'

$ cat script.sh
source sourceme
ll

When I run the script it says ./script.sh: line 2: ll: command not found. If I run the source command in the terminal the alias works without any issue.
Why it is not working inside a script?

man bash tells: For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

You forgot to turn on alias expansion. It is not sufficient for an alias to be defined, you also have to enable the expansion.
